# How to separate two signals which have same frequency and phase but generated from different positions?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency

How to separate two signals which have same frequency and phase but generated from different positions? For example, the EEG signals, we assume there are only two positions, position A and position B are separated but they generate electrical signals at same frequency and phase with different amplitude. When we measured the signal, the signal is the combine of signals from A and B. How to separate these two signals? Anyone has some idea? Many thanks.

Comment: If the signals also happen at the same time, you can't. Unless you add sensors that pick up a different mix of both signals.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a little bit more? Perhaps adding what are you trying to do, what is the context of the problem, maybe things you may have tried so far (?). In general, the condition that you describe would be an [ill-posed problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem) and it would need additional signals to be able to discriminate what exactly is happening with the source.

Comment: [Array processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_processing)?

Comment: You have more than one electrode, right?